# How to concat dataframes with missing indices

Tags: pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I have a list of multicolumn dataframes like

    `A
idx b    c
0
0.1 0.5  1
0.2 0.2  2
0.3 0.4  3
.   .    .
.   .    .
.   .    .
0.9 0.1  2
1   0.5  6`

I want to concatenate them in one DF like:

    `A      B
idx b    c e    f
0          ......
0.1 0.5  1 ......
0.2 0.2  2
0.3 0.4  3
.   .    .
.   .    .
.   .    .
0.9 0.1  2
1   0.5  6 ......`

using only the index column one and appending all the dataframes next to the first one. Unfortunately some of the dataframe are missing some of the indices e.g. `0.1, 0.2, {missing 0.3}, 0.4, ... 1`

I tried using 

`df = pd.concat(dfs, axis=0)`

but what I get is df with 80 rows ( as much as I expect, because I have a list of 40 2-column dataframes )
but another 400 rows because it adds every df as row also.
How to deal with that?

Comment: Do you think `df = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1)` ?

Comment: `axis=0` means concat horizontally.

Comment: But I want horizontal concatenation as result. Why you suppose me using axis=1 ?

Comment: @Zarrie have you tried `df = df.join(dfs)`?

Comment: @Joe, yes! And It's still creating extra rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you could try in this way:

```
index = df.index
df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
dfs.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
df = df.join(dfs)
df = df.set_index(index)
```

Comment: Thank you, Joe!
FIY this also worked for me :

`index = [0.1, 0.2, ..., 1]
df = df.reindex(index)
df.join(dfs)`